# MySql Or statement functionally not making sense

Tags: php, mysql

Why is it that the MySql "or" operator behaves like an "and" operator?

Example:

```
mysql>SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
    ->WHERE daily_typing_pages= 250 OR  
    ->daily_typing_pages= 220 OR  daily_typing_pages= 170; 
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

why does it select all 3 records. Shouldn't it return the first match and be done with it? My mind right now is telling me that the "and" operator is the one that should by nature return all 3 rows. This behavior is different than how programming languages like PHP work. Any references to official documentation would be helpful or links to how the `OR` and the `AND` work would help too.

Comment: It returns all rows that matches your query. If you will use `AND` operator in your query there will be no results at all.

Comment: Check boole algebra. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just read the query out loud like this.

I want everything from my employee table if daily typing pages is 250, or if daily typing pages is 220, or if daily typing pages is 170.

If you told me to get you all drinks from 7-11 that are either orange, blue, or green. I'd bring you back all those drinks.

If you want to limit, you need to explicitly state it:

```
SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
    ->WHERE daily_typing_pages= 250 OR  
    ->daily_typing_pages= 220 OR  daily_typing_pages= 170 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I like that example. It all makes sense now!

Comment: Now what if one did not match. Would it skip that one and return the other two?

Comment: Correct, if something doesn't match it will ignore it but return what does match. You can also use limit to define a set of results, i.e. if I want want 2 total employees, but I want to skip the first one I would do LIMIT 2,1

Answer (score 1):

All three records match the criteria you set in your `WHERE` statement as those rows have a `daily_typing_pages` value of 250, 220, *or* 170. In other words, any row that matches any of those values will be returned.

If you used `AND` *none* of those rows would be returned as none of them have a value of 250 *and* 220 *and* 170.

Comment: When you said,  none of them have a value of 250 and 220 and 170." did you mean that nonce of them have these values in that exact same sequence?

Comment: None of them had all of those values

Comment: Oh ok got you. None of them have all three values in one single column